# Using TypeScript and Express, views do not render. Instead server files are shown

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, typescript, httpserver

I'm trying to create a webapp using TypeScript. I have my app.js file creating a server, but the route I'm defining is never hit. Instead, files on the server at the root of the project are shown.

Here is my code.

```
//app.ts
import * as express from 'express';
import * as http from 'http-server';

let app = express();

app.set('port', 443);
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req: any, res: any) {
    // This code is never reached on 'GET /' requests.
    res.render('index');
});

app.use(function(req: any, res: any, next: any) {});
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {});

http.createServer().listen(app.get('port'));

console.log("Listening...");
```

When I go to `localhost:443` I'm met with the image below.

[image: showing server files instead of rendering]

In messing around with the code I'm able to do an `app.render()` call to see the rendered HTML as a string in the debugger, which is more than I can get out of this configuration, but even still just calling `app.render('index');` doesn't actually render anything. Sample below.

```
app.render('index', function(err: Error, html: string) {
    console.log(html); // Outputs the rendered view, but it is not rendered on the page.
});
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used your express instance as server.

You need to do this

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'));
```

Or

```
app.listen(app.get('port'))
```

Basically you called your server without any handler, so it shows your directory of main script.

You have created express instance, but did not added to `http` server.

Comment: With TypeScript, the http-server package doesn't support `http.createServer(app)` only `http.createServer(Options? | undefined);` so I was unable to use this. Your second solution, however, did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The directory of the views you are trying to load needs to be a full path, rather than a relative path. Try:

`app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`